# Access items from my Testimonials in my view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, episerver

I have created a block type called TestomonialSliderBlock:

```
public class TestimonialSliderBlock : BlockData
    {

        [CultureSpecific]
        [Display(GroupName = SystemTabNames.Content, Order = 300)]
        [AllowedTypes(typeof(TestimonialBlock))]
        public virtual ContentArea Testimonials { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [CultureSpecific]
        [Display(Order = 70)]
        [SelectOne(SelectionFactoryType = typeof(TestimonialBackgroundSelectionFactory))]
        public virtual string TestimonialBackgroundColor { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The ContentArea accepts content of type: TestimonialBlock:

```
public class TestimonialBlock : SiteBlockData, ProductDetailsData, IndustryDetailsData, InsightsDetailsStandardData, ProductOverviewLevel2Data, ProductOverviewLevel3Data, CustomerDetailsData, ISpaceableData
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Order = 10)]
        [UIHint(UIHint.Image)]
        public virtual ContentReference Image { get; set; }

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [CultureSpecific]
        [Display(Order = 20)]
        [UIHint(UIHint.Textarea)]
        public virtual string Quote { get; set; }

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [CultureSpecific]
        [Display(Order = 30)]
        [UIHint(UIHint.Textarea)]
        public virtual string QuoteAuthor { get; set; }

        [CultureSpecific]
        [Display(Order = 40)]
        public virtual Url Link { get; set; }

        [CultureSpecific]
        [Display(Order = 50)]
        public virtual string LinkText { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [CultureSpecific]
        [Display(Order = 60)]
        [SelectOne(SelectionFactoryType = typeof(TwoValueHorizontalPositionSelectionFactory))]
        public virtual string ImagePosition { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [CultureSpecific]
        [Display(Order = 70)]
        [SelectOne(SelectionFactoryType = typeof(TestimonialBackgroundSelectionFactory))]
        public virtual string BackgroundColor { get; set; }


        #region ISpaceableData

        [Display(Order = 10, GroupName = Global.GroupNames.Spacings)]
        [SelectOne(SelectionFactoryType = typeof(PaddingTopSelectionFactory))]
        public virtual string PaddingTop { get; set; }

        [Display(Order = 20, GroupName = Global.GroupNames.Spacings)]
        [SelectOne(SelectionFactoryType = typeof(PaddingBottomSelectionFactory))]
        public virtual string PaddingBottom { get; set; }

        #endregion ISpaceableData


        public override int WordCount
        {
            //// TODO: count in images
            get { return this.Quote.WordCount(); }
            set { }
        }
    }
```

In my view, I would like to be able to access things like Quote, QuoteAuthor, Link, LinkText etc..

I have tried the following:

```
<section>
    <div class="@Model.TestimonialBackgroundColor">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">






                @foreach (var testimonial in (Model.Testimonials.FilteredItems ?? new ContentArea().FilteredItems))
                {
                    var item = testimonial.GetContent();


<p>@item.Quote;</p>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

But when I try `@item.Quote` for example, I am unable to access Quote, QuoteAuthor, etc.. of each TestimonialBlock item listed in my Testimonials ContentArea?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `item` object would be an `IContent` instance. Have you tried converting it to your block type?

Something like:

```
var item = testimonial.GetContent() as TestimonialBlock;

if (item != null) {
   <p>@item.Quote</p>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you still need an answer for this (seven months later!), the best approach is to not try to access your block-specific properties from your TestimonialSliderBlock razor view at all.  Instead, just render the ContentArea in that view and then create a controller and view for your TestimonialBlock itself.  Episerver is smart enough that when you render the ContentArea property, it will find the right views for all of the blocks in that ContentArea property and execute their controllers and views.

So, in the Razor template for TestimonialSliderBlock, just do this:

```
@Html.PropertyFor(m => m.Testimonials)
```

Then, create a controller and view for your TestimonialBlock:

```
public class TestimonialBlockController : BlockController<TestimonialBlock>
{
...
}
```

Create a TestimonialBlock view too and inside that view, you'll have access to all of the TestimonialBlock properties:

```
@model TestimonialBlock

<p>@Model.Quote</p>
```